# scanf_s doesn't work with printf in Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I wrote these code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char input[50]={0};
    scanf_s("%s",input);
    printf("%s",input);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in release mode (Ctrl+F5) it doesn't print anything, but in debug mode (F5) it does, and has no errors. In release mode console screen is something like this:

```
abcd
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The first line is my input, and this is the screen in debug mode:

```
abcd
abcdPress any key to continue . . .
```

When I use scanf instead of scanf_s, it does print, both in debug and release mode. What am I missing?

Comment: The key factor is that the printf is actually printing into a buffer, and eventually, that buffer is  passed to the terminal.  There are a number of ways to force the buffer to be actually printed. 1) end the format string with '\n'  2) follow the printf with fflush(stdout)  3) perform a input function from the terminal.

Comment: just for a heads-up, 1) the returned value from scanf (and family) should always be checked to assure the input/conversion was successful.  2) the code has no limit on the length of the input string, so a buffer overflow can occur.  suggest using: 'if( 1 != scanf_s("%49s",input) { handle error}'  and actually, using fscanf() would be even better than scanf_s, because fscanf is available everywhere and scanf_s is not

Comment: @user3629249 Wow that's impressive. I learned a lot from you guys. Thank you very much.
But when you said 'fscanf is available everywhere', does it mean "everywhere"?

Comment: @user3629249 By the way can I use fscanf to replace scanf totally?

Comment: [Reacting the comments in Iharob's answer.] We're hijacking Iharob's answer. Ask a new question about the problems of `fgets` and 0-bytes in the input (look for a duplicate before, I couldn't find one, though I can't believe there isn't one, that's a well-known issue); get 20 rep so we can move this discussion to chat; or we follow [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284879/1741125) to chat, which I've never tried but I'm interested if it works ;)

Comment: And I tried it with `scanf`, detecting zero-bytes with `%s` requires counting input bytes with `%n`, but is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of `scanf()` requires one more argument, the correct way to call it is

```
scanf_s("%49s", input, 50);
```

and also, `scanf()` returns a value, you should not ignore it, never

```
if (scanf_s("%49s", input, 50) == 1)
    printf("%s\n", input);
```

also, add the `'\n'` to flush the output stream without the need for `fflush()`, and make your compiler as annoying as possible with warnings.

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. It's not, but please get used to using it, because it prevents problems, always write safe code, and you will be happy....

Comment: The third argument is there to prevent buffer overflows right?

Comment: @CoolGuy it is, but if you check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w40768et.aspx) they still use the length specifier.

Comment: Your answers are very informative. I wish I could vote it up. But I have only 1 reputation point...

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. If the length specifier isn't given, and the user provides more than 49 non-whitespace characters, the program will crash. If it is given, the program can check for that (possibly by use of a `%n` specification) and react accordingly. Which raises the question why to use `scanf_s` in the first place...

Comment: @mafso I don't know but I tested and it didn't crash. It just gives a null string (input[0]=0).

Comment: @iharob But if I use a dynamic string so how can I change the "49" in "%49s"?

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. You're right, my bad. It's not a runtime constraint-violation, but a matching failure. That is, you can recover if such input is given, but you lose the input read so far.

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. That's a general design-flaw of `scanf` (and the like). You can 1)build the format string at run-time (`snprintf`/`sprintf`), which is easy to get wrong and reduces the compiler's ability to warn about malformed format strings/non-matching arguments; 2) omit the width (see my last comment), which may make error handling tricky, and the input provided is lost on a matching failure; or 3) use something else than `scanf` etc

Comment: @mafso I don't know much about the (1). But the (2) I think the error can be handled by checking if input[0]=0. However that the input provided is lost on a matching failure is still a disadvantage. About number (3), I saw many suggestions to use cin/cout from C++, which I don't know. I sometimes use fgets, it has buffer overflow protection, and the length can be adjusted, I just wonder if it is a good choice (its portability).

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. `fgets` is part of C89, and I'd expect it to be present on every system. `fgets` is fine in general, although you cannot handle 0-bytes in the input properly (why I wouldn't use it in production code). It differs from `scanf` with `%s` as it reads up to (and including) a newline character (or until the buffer is full), while `scanf` stops on any white space character (which is left unread in the stream).

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. Ad 1) `char fmt[1+3+1+1]; /* 3 digits max. */ sprintf(fmt, "%%%zus", sizeof input - 1); scanf_s(fmt, input, (int) sizeof input);`. I personally try to avoid this whenever possible, though.

Comment: @mafso Could you tell me more about fgets "can't handle 0-bytes in the input properly"?

Comment: @V.T.T.Pham. An input like "foo\0bar" cannot be distinguished from an input like "foo" (to some degree, this can be detected, but not in a practical way).